# Getting decimal value from binary number

Tags: binary, rounding-unit

I have the following binary number:

$$0.11001001000100000$$

$0$ is the sign and the rest is the mantissa.

I convert it into decimal $$0.785400390625$$ and by multiplying it by $4$ I get $3.1416015625.$

Now I need to do the same with

$$0.110010010000111111$$

By I'm not able to get the correct result because I need 18 decimals and my calculator doesn't allow this. Any ideas?

Comment: Doing multiplication by hand?

Comment: Maybe this is an example to support the idea that elementary arithmetic doesn't get as much respect as it deserves. People think the way to do arithmetic is by using a calculator. In reality, even when you have a calculator, that works only with the simplest examples, and conveys no understanding.

Comment: According to an online calculator the decimal value is 0.785396575927734375 now I need to multiply it by 4 and get result with 18 decimals

Comment: No it doesn't. http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/

Comment: Thanks it's correct.!

Answer (score 2):

You start with
$$ x = 0.110010010000111111_\text{two}.$$
Multiplying by $4$ is just moving the binary point over two places:
$$ 4x = 11.0010010000111111_\text{two}.$$

The first two digits represent $3.$

Now the rest:
\begin{align}
& 0.0010010000111111_\text{two} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {2^3} + \frac 1 {2^6} + \frac 1 {2^{11}} + \frac 1 {2^{12}} + \frac 1 {2^{13}} + \frac 1 {2^{14}} + \frac 1 {2^{15}} + \frac 1 {2^{16}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{2^{13} + 2^{10} +  2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1 + 1}{2^{16}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{8192 + 1024 + 32+16+8+4+2+1}{65\,536} = \frac{9279}{65\,536}
\end{align}

Now you can do long division:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
& & & & & 0 & . & 1 & 4 & 1 &  \\  \\
65536 & ) & 9 & 2 & 7 & 9 & . & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& & 6 & 5 & 5 & 3 & & 6 \\  \\
& & 2 & 7 & 2 & 5 & & 4 & 0 \\
& & 2 & 6 & 2 & 1 & & 4 & 4 \\  \\
& & & 1 & 0 & 3 & & 9 & 6 & 0 \\
& & &   & 6 & 5 & & 5 & 3 & 6 \\  \\
& & &   & 3 & 8 & & 4 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\
& & &   & 3 & 2 & & 7 & 6 & 8 & 0 \\  \\
& & &   &   & 5 & & 6 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
& & &   &   & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
$\ldots\,$and so on$\,\ldots$

( . . . and notice that there's no need to avoid the use of a calculator in doing this.)

**PS:** The process must terminate since the denominator, $65536,$ is a power of $2,$ and $2$ is a divisor of $10.$ It terminates at the step where the remainder is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

So if
$$
x_1=0.11001001000100000_2
$$
in binary, you know what $4x_1$ is in decimal. Now you have
$$x_2=0.110010010000111111_2,$$
and you need to calculate $4x_2$.

This is really simple. A paper and pencil calculation (if mental arithmetic is not your forte) shows you that
$$
x_1-x_2=0.000000000000000001_2=2^{-18}.
$$
Therefore
$$
4x_2=4x_1-4\cdot2^{-18}=4x_1-\frac1{2^{16}}.
$$
I'm sure your calculator can manage that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to write $$0.110010010000111111\cdots$$

We can use

> In binary
>   $$0.111111111\cdots=1$$
>   Just like in decimal system,
>   $$0.99999999\cdots=1$$

Proof
$$0.1111111\cdots=0.11111111\cdots+0.00000000\cdots $$$$0.1111111\cdots=0.11111111\cdots+0.00000000\cdots1 $$
$$0.11111111\cdots=1.000000\cdots$$

> Using the identity
>   $$0.110010010000111111\cdots=01100100100010000$$

Or

> IF YOU DIDN'T MEAN THAT

We can write,
$$0.110010010000111111+0.000000000000000001=0.110010010001000000$$
Hence converting to BCD and multiplying by 4,
$$x+\frac{4}{2^{18}}=3.141\cdots$$
$$x=3.141\cdots-\frac{4}{2^{18}}$$